# Android - Starting a Service on Boot

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, android-bluetooth, gatt

I'm trying to start an Android Service on Boot that entails starting advertisements on boot which can be read by a BLE scanner. Do you know how to go about doing so? Currently, I keep getting "Unfortunately, 'myService' has stopped." Note: I am using Xamarin for Android development.

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Post the crash log and stacktrace from the logcat

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you need to register a BroadcastReceiver for the system intent "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" on your Android manifest. However, if your application is installed on the external storage use "android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE". From this BroacastReceiver you can then start your Service.

There's a nice tutorial [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/12/11/automatically-starting-services-in-android-after-booting/) that should meet your needs. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android) other SO question which has a detailed explanation on the subject.